# MQTT Application connect with two brokers using single client app/library

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am using [MQTT Eclipse Paho](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) Java Library (JAR) for connection to a MQTT broker.

But I want to connect with two brokers using the same library. I have implemented code to connect with two brokers, it does connect but problem is that after sometime connection randomly disconnects (Either one of the connection).

So what is the best way to connect with two MQTT Brokers using one MQTT client library.

**Updated**

My code for connection looks like below:

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
Class com.test.A
{
    MqttClient mMqttClient;
    A()
    {
         mMqttClient = new MqttClient("broker_url_1", "Client1", persistence);

         // Create MQTT connection options 
         MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
         connOpts.setCleanSession(true); // Create new clear session

         mMqttClient.connect(connOpts);
    }
}

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
Class com.test.B
{
    MqttClient mMqttClient;
    B()
    {
         mMqttClient = new MqttClient("broker_url_2", "Client2", persistence);

         // Create MQTT connection options 
         MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
         connOpts.setCleanSession(true); // Create new clear session

         mMqttClient.connect(connOpts);
    }    
}
```

Error That I am getting after connection lots `connectionLost: cause: Connection lost`

Comment: Show us the code you've used and any error message from the brokers/client when they disconnect

Comment: @hardillb : Please check updated question.

Comment: That code doesn't really help, as both clients look to be transient variables in the constructors so with out another reference to them will be collected at some random time after initialisation. The Error isn't that useful either, I'd check the broker logs to see if they are more forth coming

Comment: Please check updated code. Currently I don't see any broker logs I need to check how to get these logs, will post them as soon as get broker logs.

Answer (score 1):

To workaround losing connections try enabling automatic reconnect feature:

```
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpts.setCleanSession(true); // Create new clear session
connOpts.setAutomaticReconnect(true); // add this line
```

To get verbose error messages create the [jsr47min.properties](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Paho/Log_and_Debug_in_the_Java_client) file and:

```
mMqttClient = new MqttClient("broker_url_1", "Client1", persistence);
Debug debug = mMqttClient.getDebug();
debug.dumpClientDebug();   // call at different points in your code?
```

Comment: MQTT Paho does not have `connOpts.setAutomaticReconnect(true);`

Comment: Of course it does have [setAutomaticReconnect](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttConnectOptions.html) method

Comment: Version mismatch I am using 0.4.0 and it is in the latest release.

Comment: Well you didn't care to provide that information in the question

Comment: The problem was something else, found after deep debugging.